# How to check implementation details of 'watch' command?

Tags: command-line, source-code

To maximise learning I ended up cloning whole linux source code from [github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux). I wanted to check how 'watch' command is implemented in it, but code is just too vast to return anything useful when I try to grep 'watch'. I was wondering if any of you can help.

Answer (score 3):

In addition.

It is in the procps package.

For example if you search the man pages of ubuntu it will normally say what package provides the code. [(Like this)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/watch.1.html)

The source code can be found [(here)](http://procps.sourceforge.net/download.html).

Direct Download:
http://procps.sourceforge.net/procps-3.2.8.tar.gz

or you could use dpkg to see what package owns a particular file like so:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/watch
```

---

**Find source code for any command**:

So if say you wanted to look at `top` source code you could:

```
whereis top
```

[image]

The binary file for `top` is "/usr/bin/top" and to find the package that owns that file:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/top
```

[image]

Make sure to:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

And then you can find the source code for a package by:

```
sudo apt-get source procps
sudo apt-get source gedit
sudo apt-get source <package-name>
```

It will download a tar in the current directory and extract it:

[image: result of apt-get source]

We should then be able to find the source code for how it works:

[image: how to download source code for a command]

Comment: May be you should try shutter: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/shutter/ for annotating images?

Comment: @Jobin Thanks I will keep it in mind for future reference. Are the blue squiggles bad?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://gitorious.org/procps/procps?p=procps:procps.git;a=blob;f=watch.c;h=40beacad487767d630aeef8ff56dcc3fe5721f8d;hb=HEAD) link might help. I just Google for watch.c

Answer (score 0):

May be you could start-off by `strace watch`.

From the [manual page of strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace):

> ```
>    strace is a useful diagnostic, instructional, and debugging tool.  Sys‐
>    tem  administrators,  diagnosticians  and trouble-shooters will find it
>    invaluable for solving problems with programs for which the  source  is
>    not  readily available since they do not need to be recompiled in order
>    to trace them.  Students, hackers and the overly-curious will find that
>    a  great  deal  can  be  learned about a system and its system calls by
>    tracing even ordinary programs.  And programmers will find  that  since
>    system  calls  and  signals  are  events that happen at the user/kernel
>    interface, a close examination of this boundary is very useful for  bug
>    isolation, sanity checking and attempting to capture race conditions.
> ```

For the actual implementation details, you will ultimately have to rely on the source code. You can take the help of tools like [csope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_vim_tutorial.html) and [ctags](http://blog.stwrt.ca/2012/10/31/vim-ctags).